# H2 database - decimal separator

Tags: sql, database, h2

I'm trying to import some data from Oracle to H2. I have a table with column type NUMBER(15,3) and insert script with value '13253,124' for that column.

Problem is, H2 cannot recognize comma as decimal separator and fails to insert the line...

Is there any way to say to H2 "use comma as decimal separator instead of dot"?

Thanks

Comment: Just convert it on import (or get Oracle to spit it out with a dot)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a dot, or, even better use a `PreparedStatement` with `setBigDecimal`.

What you try doesn't work in Oracle either, with the default settings. I could be wrong, but I think it doesn't work with any common database. Test case (using [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with Oracle):

```
create table test(x number(15,3)); 

insert into test values('13253,124');
-> invalid number : insert into test values('13253,124')

insert into test values(13253,124);
-> too many values : insert into test values(13253,124)
```

Comment: well, it was the oracle sqldeveloper export file from oracle database containing comma instead of dot for decimal separator...

Comment: OK, I guess it's a Oracle SQLDeveloper Export [bug](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2237649?tstart=0).

Comment: Wrong, in Oracle you can use both decimal separors, check NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS settings in Oracle https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams129.htm#REFRN10126

Comment: @MikeAdamenko notice I wrote "with the default settings"

Comment: @ThomasMueller Well, the default settings for  NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS is operating system-dependent

Comment: @MikeAdamenko I believe NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS affects TO_NUMBER and TO_CHAR, but not the case above. But feel free to add your own answer to the question! Or ask a question.